# Java JTable TableModel addRow no change

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have more of a problem than a question and hope you can help me find possible reasons for this.

In a very simple `JTable`, where I use the `DefaultTableModel`. I add a row programmatically during the runtime like this:

```
public void Update(String neu) {
    System.out.println(model.getDataVector());

    model.addRow(new String[] {neu});

    System.out.println(model.getDataVector());
}
```

The System-Prints are only a debugging measure for me to realize more.
Whenever this method runs, I actually add something to the `TableModel` (prove due to the out.prints)

But the change is not permanent. Neither do I see a change in my table, nor is the "new value" part of the `TableModel` the next time the method Update is called.

What could be the reason?

**Edit1:** Sadly I cannot make a code snippet small enough to be posted here and yet contain the error. I would highly appreciate it however if you guys could give me some hints in generall what might cause the abovementioned behaviour.

**EDIT2:** I have build a workaround in my code. Somehow the problem seemed to be caused by using two different frames for this operation (one frame to ask for the value and the second frame to use and display this value)

I replaced one frame with a JDialog and now the TableModel updates correctly. I do not know what the problem with using two frames was, but at least I have my code working again. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I see you printing out data from one model, and adding a row to a different model.

Comment: For better help, **thoroughly** read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then implement what you've learned from the reading

Comment: @peeskillet You are of course absolutely right and I should have done this from the beginning. I added the sample code to demsonstrate my problem

Comment: Besides the fact that you never add the action listener to the button in the `TestFrameText` class, it works fine

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks again. Yes a Super Class handled that in the real code forgot it in this example, which makes the example work. Sadly I cannot seem to reproduce a code snippet small enough to contain the error and yet be short enough to post here... Any ideas in generall how such an error as mentioned above might occur?

Comment: You could be referencing the wrong model.

Answer (score 0):

When you change data in tableModel, table is not repainted. Try to call `model.fireTableDataChanged();` after adding new row to table model.

**EDIT:**
`fireTableDataChanged` will not solve your problem, because it is called automatically as mentioned in comment below.

Another problem I see is that you have two different fields/data models - `mdlUebersetzung` and `model`. One that you use for loggin, one for addingRow. Is it same instance of TableModel?

Comment: This is done automatically by the `DefaultTableModel` and calling `fireTableRowsInserted` is actually much more efficient

Comment: Sorry. I replaced mdlUebersetzung by model but forgot the ones in the print. It is only one model in the real code

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write this simple example using exactly your method and it looks like it works.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class MyTable extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    private JButton addButton; // by clicking the button a new row will be added to the table

    // just create the table and set up the interface
    public MyTable() {
        table = new JTable(0,1); // this creates a new Table with 0 rows and 1 column having a DefaultTableModel
        model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

        JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(table);

        addButton = new JButton("Add row");
        addButton.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(addButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(tablePanel);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == addButton) {
            Update("new Row text");
        }
    }

    public void Update(String neu) {
        System.out.println(model.getDataVector());

        model.addRow(new String[] {neu});

        System.out.println(model.getDataVector());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MyTable();
    }
}
```

The thing I noticed is that if I create the JTable using the constructor with no arguments, i.e. `new JTable()`, the rows added to the model are all empty (which can be noticed looking at the prints in the terminal), even if I'm passing `new String[] {neu}` as argument. This is weird because according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable--) that constructor should return a JTable having a "default data model", which I guess is obtained by calling the `createDefaultDataModel()` method of JTable, whose [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#createDefaultDataModel--) says in turn that by default it returns a `DefaultTableModel`.

**EDIT:**
I noticed now that the constructor for `DefaultTableModel` with no arguments builds a table model with "zero columns and zero rows".

As noted by peeskillet in a comment, always remember to add the action listener to the buttons to actually make them do something!

Comment: thank you for your help. The code snippet did indeed work in the end but the problem with the real code lies somewhere else. Any ideas in general what might cause a behaviiour as mentioned in the question above?

Comment: since you don't see the change in the table nor the change will result in subsequent calls, but still see the correct values printed out in terminal the first thing I would do is to double check that you're actually adding the new rows to the correct model. Is it possible that you're modifying a different istance of the table model?

Comment: It is the right model. I replaced the model with table.getModel() and still got the same result.

Comment: that's weird. I can only think that for some reason at some point the model is emptied. If you can, try to debug your code - it should be possible to set a breakpoint on any access to the model meber of your class. This way you can see if something is modifying it.